# Testing archive with 7-zip

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I recently had an issue with corrupted archive files and read about 7-zip being able to test archive files.  Would this be useful for trying to fix or remove corrupted archive files for me? If so, how do I use 7-zip?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the archive file with 7-zip manager and click on the `Test` button

[image]

If you prefer CLI, `7z t <archive-name>` does the same. But I doubt you can use it for anything beyond verification of the archive integrity.

Comment: it said that there were no errors in any of the files so either this is not applicable to my issue or the ebay seller lied to me...

Comment: @Glenn Could you elaborate more ? You purchased something over eBay and the seller sent you a link to download something ?

Comment: no, he said that the archive files were corrupted but that someone who knew computers could avoid the problem, so I figured why not test the archive files... I don't know if this really proves anything, but I'm trying to figure out if what he said makes any sense.

Comment: Looking at your past questions, I think you're speaking about [this](http://superuser.com/questions/192784/corrupted-archive-file-on-just-cause-2-game-disc) - it's as I said if an archive it corrupted, there's very little you can do, except fix it from the source, which in case is your eBay dealer. I'd go back to him and ask for a refund/replacement.

Comment: okay, i was hoping I wouldn't have to do that.  Oh well, looks like that's all that's left to do.

Comment: "Import edition, but has an option to install full English version.
Game is in excellent condition but has a corrupted archive file. Please realize this when purchasing. A small nuisance but can be averted by someone who is computer savvy. Thus the low price." This was a part of the description...

Comment: Yes, 7-Zip has a test button, but there's no documentation I can find about what it does. Does it check the central directory CRC? The CRC at the end of the ZIP file? Does it compare the archive's data to the external file (pretty sure the answer to that question is NO). So, what good is a test feature with no explanation of what the result means?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the command line to check the archive:

```
$ 7z t <filename>.7z
```

Here is the man page for reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't be easier. Simply download [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) (or via [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com)) and then open up the archive you want and click the `Test` button.
[image]

Comment: Or install 7zip, right click on the .zip file in windows, choose "7 zip" menu -> "test archive" submenu option.